# From a rendered list of flights, how does one access the specific flight-data which relates to the flight's booking-button that has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, event-handling, dom-events, event-delegation

From a fetched array of flight-data items I was able to created a table with each row displaying its specific flight-data alongside a button for booking the related flight.

I want to add each button into an array so that I can use the array in order to **1)** access the currently booked flight flight and **2)** add/display it to/at a cart.

The problem I have is that the array `bookedFlights` never gets appended so I can't access the button that's been clicked to use later.

How could one access the specific flight-data which relates to the button that has been clicked?

```
const fl = fetch("https://mocki.io/v1/fa695c4b-475e-4dfc-8608-952c0c5a28b5");

fl.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
}).then((result) => {
  const fakeFlights = result.flights;
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  const thead1 = document.createElement("thead");
  const thead2 = document.createElement("thead");
  const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  const bookingButtons = [];
  let row1 = document.createElement("tr");
  let row2 = document.createElement("tr");
  let headingTH = document.createElement("th");
  headingTH.innerText = "Available Flights";
  headingTH.colSpan = 7;
  row1.appendChild(headingTH);
  thead1.appendChild(row1);
  for (key in fakeFlights[0]) {
    let heading = document.createElement("th");
    if (key === "flightNumber") {
      key = "Flight Number"
    }
    if (key === "departureTime") {
      key = "Departure Time"
    }
    if (key === "arrivalTime") {
      key = "Arrival Time"
    }
    heading.innerText = key;
    row2.appendChild(heading);
  }
  let heading = document.createElement("th");
  heading.innerText = "Book the flight";
  row2.appendChild(heading);
  thead2.appendChild(row2);
  for (let i = 0; i < fakeFlights.length; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (key in fakeFlights[i]) {
      let rowData = document.createElement("td");
      rowData.innerHTML = fakeFlights[i][key];
      row.appendChild(rowData);
    }
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerText = "Book";
    btn.id = i;
    bookingButtons.push(btn);
    row.appendChild(btn);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  table.append(thead1, thead2, tbody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  let bookedFlights = [];
  for (let selectedButton of bookingButtons) {
    selectedButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      bookedFlights.push(selectedButton.id);
    });
  }
  const data = {
    flights: fakeFlights,
    bookedFlights: bookedFlights
  }
  return data;
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data.flights[data.bookedFlights[0]]);
}).catch(() => {
  document.write("error")
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend using [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) instead of adding 41 seperate event listeners.

Comment: Take a look at the way you're pushing data into `bookedFlights`. It only occurs if you click on a button. Should it work like that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The OP might consider reading [_"How do I ask a good question?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially considering the advices of [_"How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thus the OP should come up with an array of maybe just 3 flight-data items which the OP together with the rest of the code could provide as executable [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) code.

Comment: **Other suggestions besides** the already mentioned [**event delegation**](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... The OP also might consider separating the code into specialized task, hence just **a single properly named [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)** for each, the fetching, the rendering and the event handling task. Thus one avoids nested and therefore more difficult to read / debug / maintain anonymous function expressions provided within promise and event handling methods.

Comment: @LearningCode ... It was nice of the OP if the OP engages with any kind of feedback.

Comment: @LearningCode ... Regarding the so far provided sole answer are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

The two main improvement patterns / techniques are ...

- [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) which for the OP's provided environment means, one has to register a single event listener exactly once, either at the `table` related element node, or even better, at the table body's related element node since the latter is the common single parent node of all flight-related table-data.
- [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is another one. In its most basic implementation, targeting the OP's originally provided code, this means just a single properly named function statement for each ...

  - the fetching (`fetchAndDisplayFlightData` ),
  - the rendering (`createFlightOverview` ),
  - the event handling (`handleBookingOfSelectedFlight...`),

  ... task.

The final implementation features following techniques / methods ...

- `fetchAndDisplayFlightData` expects and URL where it does `fetch` the flight-data from. Within this function one creates the flight-data overview, here an html table element, by passing the response-data's `flights`-array to `createFlightOverview`.
- The latter function does process this list of flights (`listOfFlights`) mostly via the code originally provided by the OP. There are some improvements though, like ...

  - ... using an object based `headerContentLookup` in order to access the correct table header content via each of a data-item's keys.
  - ... making use, for each rendered data-item's *"Booking"*-button, of the [global `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) `data-flight-number` and its related [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) `flightNumber` since the latter is exactly what identifies a flight (or flight-data item).
- As already mentioned, there is exactly one `'click'`-handler going to be registered at the table-element's table-body element. The very handler function is implemented `this`-context aware, thus it expects a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)-instance to be [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). And the latter data gets created by a helper function (`createFlightNumberBasedFlightDataMap`) which does [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the response-data's `flights`-array according by each flight-data item's `flightNumber`-value that is used as a flight-item's identifier-`key`.

  - The registered `'click'`-handler which got ad-hoc created via `bind` implements the functionality of `handleBookingOfSelectedFlightFromBoundFlightDataMap` and thus expects a [`click`-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) and such an event's [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). In case its [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) element matches a button-element one can proceed with extracting the `flightNumber` from the very element's `dataset` property. The flight-number value then will be used for accessing the related flight-item from the lookup/map via [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get).
  - Within a final step one could pass the selected flight-data to yet another function like e.g. ... `bookSelectedFlight(selectedFlightData)`.

```js
// - the OP's own originally provided (most of it) table creation code.
function createFlightOverview(listOfFlights) {
  const headerContentLookup = {
    departureTime: 'Departure Time',
    arrivalTime: 'Arrival Time',
    flightNumber: 'Flight Number',
    destination: 'Destination',
    origin: 'Origin',
    price: 'Price',
  };
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  const thead1 = document.createElement("thead");
  const thead2 = document.createElement("thead");
  const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

  // - not needed.
  // const bookingButtons = [];

  const row1 = document.createElement("tr");
  const row2 = document.createElement("tr");
  const headingTH = document.createElement("th");

  headingTH.textContent = "Available Flights";
  headingTH.colSpan = 7;

  row1.appendChild(headingTH);
  thead1.appendChild(row1);

  Object
    .keys(listOfFlights[0])
    .forEach(key => {
      const heading = document.createElement("th");
      heading.textContent = headerContentLookup[key] ?? key;
      row2.appendChild(heading);
    });
  const heading = document.createElement("th");
  heading.textContent = "Book the flight";

  row2.appendChild(heading);
  thead2.appendChild(row2);

  listOfFlights
    .forEach(flightItem => {
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      Object
        .values(flightItem)
        .forEach(value => {
          const cellData = document.createElement("td");
          cellData.textContent = value;
          row.appendChild(cellData);
        });
      const btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.textContent = "Book";

      // - not recommended.
      // btn.id = i;

      // - for the flight identification rather use
      //   a data-item's `flightNumber` provided as
      //   global `data-*` attribute ... like  e.g.
      btn.dataset.flightNumber = flightItem.flightNumber;

      // - not needed.
      // bookingButtons.push(btn);

      row.appendChild(btn);
      tbody.appendChild(row);
    });
  table.append(thead1, thead2, tbody);

  return table;
}

// - helper task which creates a `Map` instance from an array of flight
//   related data-items, based on each item's `flightNumber` value. 
function createFlightNumberBasedFlightDataMap(listOfFlights) {
  return new Map(
    listOfFlights
      .map(flightItem => [flightItem.flightNumber, flightItem])
  )
}

// - the final task which actually is going to trigger the
//   booking-process for the before selected flight-item.
function bookSelectedFlight(flightData) {
  console.log({ selectedFlightData: flightData });
}
// - the handler function which is aware of a bound `this` context
//   where `this` refers to the one time created (and bound)
//   flight number based lookup.
function handleBookingOfSelectedFlightFromBoundFlightDataMap({ target }) {
  const flightDataMap = this;
  const elmButton = target.closest('button');

  if (elmButton) {
    const { flightNumber } = elmButton.dataset ?? null;
    const selectedFlightData = flightDataMap.get(flightNumber);

    console.log({ elmButton, flightNumber/*, selectedFlightData*/ });

    bookSelectedFlight(selectedFlightData);
  }
}

// - the OP's provided example code changed according to the suggestions.
function fetchAndDisplayFlightData(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(flightData => {

      const listOfFlights = flightData.flights;
      const flightOverview = createFlightOverview(listOfFlights);

      // - register the button specific click-handling at the table's body.
      flightOverview
        .querySelector('tbody')
        .addEventListener(
          'click',
          // - create a handler function which has a flight number based
          //   `Map` instance as lookup table bound to its `this` context.
          handleBookingOfSelectedFlightFromBoundFlightDataMap
            .bind(
              createFlightNumberBasedFlightDataMap(listOfFlights)
            )
        );
      document
        .body
        .appendChild(flightOverview);
    })
    .catch(reason => 
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(String(reason)))
    );
}

fetchAndDisplayFlightData(
  'https://mocki.io/v1/fa695c4b-475e-4dfc-8608-952c0c5a28b5'
);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 0 100px 0; zoom: .9; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100px!important; }
```